# List of all currencies which can be mined by a SHA256-based ASIC miner

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

Lot of information over this scattered over the internet, but can someone list complete list of currencies that can be mined by an AntMiner U2 apart from bitcoin, or any other SHA256-based miner?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to touch this
https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/views/all/
Need to filter out those which aren't sha256d though.

Comment: Superb List! I wish they had listed the currency algorithms

Comment: Yep, hope in the future they will have it :D